# Ignoring incoming bytes on a Linux TCP socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I want to connect to a server, and synchronously write(2) to it.

At some point, buffers are filling up and I need to read(2) to let me continue writing.

read(2) is of course copying lots of bytes unnecessarily, and it's blocking if I don't know how many bytes to expect.

How can I discard incoming bytes on a TCP socket?

I've tried `ioctl(sockfd, I_SRDOPT, RMSGD)` but it's returning errno `EFAULT` `Bad address`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to accomplish. Why is it "copying lots of bytes unnecessarily"? Do you want to use `select(2)` to see if there's data to be read so you don't block when there's nothing to read?

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with this question. Why do you want to ignore the responses the server is sending you? For one thing it might be telling you to *stop.*

Comment: @EJP - I don't understand it either.

Comment: @EJP There are very obvious use cases here. As it happens I'm stress testing a server I've written, and don't care about the responses.

Comment: In the case a user specified a buffer to small to hold data returned from the server I don't want to put the protocol in an unusable state and instead ignore the data it sends me without allocating any space

Answer (score 2):

You could use the socket in the non-blocking mode to periodically consume incoming data without blocking. To quote a [tutorial](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html):

> If you call `recv()` in non-blocking mode, it will return any data that the system has in it's read buffer for that socket. But, it won't wait for that data. If the read buffer is empty, the system will return from `recv()` immediately saying "Operation Would Block!".

Comment: Unhelpful, in the case a user specified a buffer to small to hold data returned from the server I don't want to put the protocol in an unusable state and instead ignore the data it sends me without allocating any space.